# How can I get complete class name using Selenium getAttribute?

Tags: selenium

```
class = "col-scope serialize"
```

I have an element in HTML with class name like above. When I try to get the class name with `getAttribute("class")` I am only getting the value `col-scope`.

How can I get the complete value `col-scope serialize`?

Comment: Are you sure your `class` attribute has not changed between you observed its value visually and tested it with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

As `@JaSON` mentioned in their [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336928/how-can-i-get-complete-class-name-using-selenium-getattribute/73336999#comment129515834_73336999):

> Waiting for element with exact @class to extract that exact @class doesn't really make much sense

---

### Solution

Ideally, to extract the value of the *`class`* attribute you need to use the other attributes (other than class attribute) to locate the element first and then you can use `getAttribute("class")` and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tagName[attributeName='attributeValue']")).getAttribute("class"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tagName[@attributeName='attributeValue']")).getAttribute("class"));
  ```